# Help installing Dynamic Linq extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

Im trying to follow [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx) tutorial and Haack seems to use Dynamic Linq but nowhere can I find how to install it... I know Im supposed to add a reference but Im really clueless in that area.. Im new to this, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/bb894665.aspx and accept the License agreement then you can download CSharpSamples.zip.

Answer (score 0):

I just added the source file to my solution. You can download a demo solution [here](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/04/27/38243/).